# Batch File folder detection

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Yes, I know I need to double-up the %a to be %%a when used in a batch file. ;)

This works, but does not give me the results I want - this is just too much..

```
FOR /f %a IN ('dir "D:\tomcat*" /ad /b ')  DO FOR /f %b IN ('dir "D:\%a\webapps" /ad /b ') DO ECHO D:\%a\webapps\%b
```

What I would really like to do is:

```
FOR /f %a IN ('dir "D:\tomcat*\webapps" /ad /b ')  DO ECHO %a
```

But, I get the resulting error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I would like to do this as I have a need to detect which folders have tomcat in them and could be any of the following:

```
D:\tomcat
D:\tomcat1
D:\tomcat2
D:\tomcat_1
etc.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you could use `IF EXIST`

```
FOR /f %a IN ('dir "D:\tomcat*" /ad /b ')  DO IF EXIST "%~a\webapps\nul" dir /b "%~a\webapps"
```

`\nul` is to [check if folder exist](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/65994).

Comment: You do not need the nul to check if the folder exists. Just end it with the back slash.

Comment: i like this one as it is pretty simple..  I did make a modification to be: `FOR /f %a IN ('dir "D:\tomcat*" /ad /b ')  DO IF EXIST %~a\webapps\ ECHO %~a\webapps`

Answer (score 3):

Wildcards (`?` and `*`) can only be used in the *last* item of a path, so you will have to work around that.

As an alternative method to the nested `for` loops you are using, you could also do the following:

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %A in ('dir /A:D /B "D:\tomcat*"') do (> nul 2>&1 dir /A:D "%~A\webapps" && echo "%~A")
```

This outputs all folders whose names contain `tomcat` in their names *and* have got a subdirectory called `webapps`.

You need to provide the option string `"eol=| delims="` for `for /F`; this also applies to the variant with the two nested `for` loops.