# xcopy batch folder tree

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

```
S:
cd \newclients
xcopy "s:\clients\*\MER" . /s /d
pause
```

This is my batch file. In my folder tree we have clients then names folders then MER folder. I want to be able to search the directory for the MER folder and copy that folder along with the client name before it. Is there a way to do this with batch files?

Comment: [This might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252162/some-copy-command-in-windows-to-copy-from-current-location-to-specified-location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `if exist` should do the thing.

```
pushd "s:\newclients"
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /ad "s:\clients\*"') do (
if exist "s:\clients\%%f\MER\nul" ( xcopy "s:\clients\%%f\MER" "s:\newclients" /s /d )
)
popd
pause
```

Note: Add a slash if it's to [check folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/65994) ie. `if exist "s:\clients\%%f\MER\" ...` or `if exist "s:\clients\%%f\MER\nul" ...`

To suppress prompt about destination file/folder add `/I` in [`xcopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) :

> ```
> /I    If in doubt always assume the destination is a folder
>       e.g. when the destination does not exist.
> ```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33445866/

Comment: i had to change the path of the destination to s:\newclients\%%f\mer but it keeps asking if that is a directory when copying the files over and i have to hold down the D key for it to proceed. Better then what i had! but not sure how to make it automatically go